Having some trouble with ForwardRef in python with fastapi and ormar
I have an api that has been built in fastapi and uses ormar for ORM.
My database models are defined as follows:
database = databases.Database(config.database_url)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

base_ormar_config = ormar.OrmarConfig(
    metadata=metadata,
    database=database,
)


ProjectRef = ForwardRef("Project")


class BaseModel(ormar.Model):
    ormar_config = base_ormar_config.copy(abstract=True)
    id: str = ormar.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, uuid_format="string")
    created_at: datetime.datetime = ormar.DateTime(server_default=sqlalchemy.func.now())


class User(BaseModel):
    ormar_config = base_ormar_config.copy(tablename="users")
    subscription: str = ormar.String(max_length=254, nullable=True)
    email: str = ormar.String(max_length=244, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    email: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    phone: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    company_name: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    occupation: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    projects = ormar.ManyToMany(ProjectRef)

class Project(BaseModel):
    ormar_config = base_ormar_config.copy(tablename="projects")
    owner: User = ormar.ForeignKey(User, name="owner_id")
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=244, nullable=True)
    description: str = ormar.String(max_length=555, nullable=True)
    files: list[str] = ormar.JSON(default=list)

User.update_forward_refs()

to be able to define my ManyToMany relationships I need to use Forward ref from the typing library as per the ormar docs here https://collerek.github.io/ormar/latest/relations/postponed-annotations/
An error is getting thrown when trying to run this:
PydanticUndefinedAnnotation: name 'Project' is not defined


Update forward refs on ProjectRef
